# Photography libraries software

Tags: photography, version-control

I have bunches of photos taken during life and I have some backups of the as well (but version and contents of collections may differ unfortunately), 
Is there some Software system to to manage such situations.

The main problem I want to solve that my backup And main repository can contains some different folders. Would be Like same, but some folders are missing and some are new. And that system should show me that those files are while comparing.

I know version control software may do similar things, so could be nice to have something in between git and picasa. 
Desirably (not necessary)it would run on Ubuntu gnu/linux.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. E.g. what does "manage" include: sorting them by date? grouping them by motive? finding duplicates by, uhm, what criteria? Must it be free-of-charge, or what's the budget? What OS should it run on?

Comment: Is there a reason why Git & Picasa together wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Well, I would like some one integrated system. And git might take big disk chunks even when data is deleted - it keeps remembering the past versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** The OP updated their question to add an 'Ubuntu' requirement while I was writing this.

[Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom.html) is a well known commercial photo editing and management application that may meet your requirements.

1. All Lightroom photo edits are non-destructive. The original files are untouched. This prevents the problem using GIT which would make a full copy of every version of a file.
2. Metadata regarding edits you've made are stored in a catalog file.
3. The lightroom UI shows you a list of the edits made to any particular photo and it is easy to revert to a previous version of a photo.
4. Lightrom lets you make *Virtual Copies* of photos and perform different edits on that version. Again this doesn't edit the original file. This is somewhat similar to branching of an individual file in source control.
5. There are lots of plugins available for Lightroom to help backup photos. For example, Flickr offer a large amount of storage space and you can use a plugin to export your photos there.
6. Lightroom regularly prompts you to backup your catalog file.
7. Lightroom lets you manage the metadata for your photos. For example, you can tag photos to make it easy to find them again in future.
8. When importing photos, Lightroom functionality to avoid importing duplicate photos. This is most commonly used when importing from an SD card which contains photos you've imported earlier. This may help you to merge your backup into your main repository.

There is a video discussing backup strategies for Lightroom [here](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/the-complete-picture-with-julieanne-kost/lightroom-backup-strategies-5/).

One disadvantage of Lightroom over Picasa is that Lightroom does not have built-in Face Recognition.

Personally I used Picasa and then moved to Lightroom when Lightroom 4 was released as it was priced very competitively. There is a learning curve for Lightroom but I'd definately recommend considering it. I also use Crashplan for offsite backup of my photos and catalog.

Comment: Should I delete my answer given the OPs update to require Ubuntu?

Comment: No, please leave this answer. If nothing more relevant, I will accept it Monday. that software anyway could be run in virtual mashine.